# Invalid format of event in WSO2

Tags: json, wso2, invalidation, siddhi

I am trying to deploy business rules via the API of wso2. 
I have tested the siddhi App on the editor , it works correctly. When I deploy it in the dashboard. When sending the data to the url of input, I get this error:

ERROR {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.text.sourcemapper.TextSourceMapper} - **Invalid format of event because some required attributes are missing in event** {
  "symbol": "qxyt",
  "price": 45.22,
  "volume": 33,
  "name": "Beldum"
} while needed attributes are **[Attribute{id='symbol', type=STRING}, Attribute{id='price', type=FLOAT}, Attribute{id='volume', type=LONG}, Attribute{id='name', type=STRING}]** in the stream StockInputStream of siddhi text input mapper.

I have send the json as: 
{"event":{
"symbol":"sonido",
"price":45.22,
"volume":33,
"name":"salon"
}}

and

{
"symbol":"sonido",
"price":45.22,
"volume":33,
"name":"salon"
}

but with both I get the same error.

Is wrong the way I'm sending? or how does it is supposed to be received?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using text mapping you will have to send a comma separated key value pair with new lines in between like below.

```
"symbol":"sonido", 
"price":45.22, 
"volume":33, 
"name":"salon"
```

[This](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-map-text/blob/master/component/src/test/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/map/text/sourcemapper/TextDefaultSourceMapperTestCase.java#L103) is a testcase and [this](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-map-text/api/1.0.22/) is the documentation for text mapper. If you want to send json you will have to use [json mapper](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-map-json/api/4.0.42/).